# Why does this make the bot crash?

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, discord.js

```js
bot.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    const welcomeembed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
            .setColor(0xfcdb03)
            .setTitle("Welcome")
            .addField("Welcome " + member + "** to our Discord Server!**", "Please verify yourself in " + message.guild.channels.get('723965000062074990'))
    member.guild.channels.get('723240170329079870').sendEmbed(welcomeembed); 
});
```

The bot isn't crashing when I use a regular message. Maybe I'm just using the Embed message wrong.

````
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'client', { value: message.client });
                                                           ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'client' of undefined
    at new MessageEmbed (C:\Users\456899754\Desktop\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\MessageEmbed.js:13:60)
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\456899754\Desktop\botfolder\bot.js:30:24)
    at Client.emit (events.js:310:20)
    at Guild._addMember (C:\Users\456899754\Desktop\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\Guild.js:938:19)
    at GuildMemberAddHandler.handle (C:\Users\456899754\Desktop\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\handlers\GuildMemberAdd.js:12:13)
    at WebSocketPacketManager.handle (C:\Users\456899754\Desktop\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\WebSocketPacketManager.js:102:65)
    at WebSocketConnection.onPacket (C:\Users\456899754\Desktop\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:325:35)
    at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (C:\Users\456899754\Desktop\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:288:17)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\456899754\Desktop\node_modules\ws\lib\EventTarget.js:103:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:310:20)```
````

Comment: Please post the error as that would help identify the problem.

Comment: i cant even see the error it just closes

Comment: Are there any log files generated?

Comment: what version of discord.js are you using?

Comment: I dont know what version im using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set up your environment such that you can see errors. Otherwise, how can you expect to be able to fix any problems you encounter? If you're starting your bot with a batch file or something similar, edit it and add `PAUSE` on a new line to force the window to stay open after the process terminates. Otherwise, you can try having the node process output to a file - look up ways to do this.

The problem is likely referencing `message.guild.channels.get('723965000062074990')`. There is no `message`, you're in the `guildMemberAdd` event. Use `member.guild` instead.

```
bot.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
  const welcomeembed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setColor(0xfcdb03)
    .setTitle("Welcome")
    .addField("Welcome " + member + "** to our Discord Server!**", "Please verify yourself in " + member.guild.channels.get('723965000062074990'))
  member.guild.channels.get('723240170329079870').sendEmbed(welcomeembed); 
});
```

Comment: `message.guild.channels.get('723965000062074990')` is just linking a channel

Comment: @Memag yes, but `message` refers to a *specific discord message* that you go through to get the guild the *message* was sent in. This is the `guildMemberAdd` event, there is no message associated with it, so you need to get the guild through the `member` you're given instead.

Comment: @Memag to be clear, this *absolutely* is causing an error because `message` is not defined.

Comment: I removed it completely and its still crashing

Comment: @Memag from the error you edited into your post, it looks like you needed to be using `RichEmbed` after all. Try my edited code.